# React big-calendar page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am working on a calendar page for my group project. I am using react big calendar. I need my popup window to show text of the event that can't be changed by the user. I have serveral differnt events and I want each on to give a description when that event is clicked. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
class mycalendar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="calendar  ">
        <BigCalendar
          {...this.props}
          onSelectEvent={event => Popup.alert("what's up")}
          events={eventsCalendar}
          views={{ month: true }}
          step={60}
          defaultDate={new Date()}
          style={{ height: "150vh", padding: "100px" }}
        />
        <Popup
          className="mm-popup"
          btnClass="mm-popup__btn"
          closeBtn={true}
          closeHtml={null}
          defaultOk="Ok"
          defaultCancel="Cancel"
          wildClasses={false}
          closeOnOutsideClick={true}
        />
    );
  };
}
```

Comment: Please edit your Question and fix code snippet. Also please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You could try with a fiddle or something similar. SO has its own fiddle-like system, but I'm not sure if it actually supports React. Thank you

Comment: Sorry about that I did update it. I am trying to add event info into a popup window in the react big calendar. But I have serveral events on any given day. I am stuck, any help will be appreicated. I am a new coder!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue i fixed it with state prop like this:

is the calendar component i added 'event' prop:

```
this.state = {
      event: {},
    }
```

onclickEvent i added an handler:

```
 onSelectEvent={this.eventClick}
```

the event click handler set the clicked event the the state prop:

```
eventClick = event => {
    this.setState({ eventShow: true, event })
  }
```

and send it to the popup:

```
<PopupEvent
          show={this.state.eventShow}
          onHide={this.handleOnHide}
          event={this.state.event}
        />
```

now you have the clicked event in the popup props.